# Replace new lines with a comma delimiter with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a Notepad++ question.

How can I take the below words in Notepad++ (which is on different lines)

```
Apples
Apricots
Pear
Avocados
Bananas
```

And turn them into a paragraph with a comma at the end of each one? Like this:

```
Apples, Apricots, Pear, Avocados, Bananas
```

Answer (score 389, accepted):

Open the find and replace dialog (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

Then select `Regular expression` in the 'Search Mode' section at the bottom.

In the `Find what` field enter this: `[\r\n]+`

In the `Replace with`: `,`

*There is a space after the comma.*

This will also replace lines like

```
Apples

Apricots
Pear

Avocados
Bananas
```

Where there are empty lines.

**If your lines have trailing blank spaces you should remove those first. The simplest way to achieve this is**

```
EDIT -> Blank Operations -> Trim Trailing Space
```

OR

```
TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> Trim trailing spaces
```

Be sure to set the Search Mode to "Regular expression".

Comment: If there are trailing spaces on the line you might for `_*[\r\n]+`. To deal with the blank lines turned into excess commas you could do a regular expression search for `,_[,_]+` and replace with `,_`. Alternatively, the TextFx package has a delete blanks lines command that can be used before adding the commas. (Note change underscores to spaces in these code blocks.)

Comment: yes you are very correct. I was just trying to give a minimalistic answer. Maybe I should edit the answer then.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: I see "0 occurrences were replaced."

Comment: @IainElder, Search Mode must be set to "Regular expression" instead of "Normal" or "Extended".

Comment: I had the same result as Iain.

Comment: This just saved me 10 minutes.

Comment: Did not work for me, answer by trisulphani below is waaaaay simpler. Not sure why this one is marked as answer.

Answer (score 39):

Here's what worked for me with a similar list of strings in Notepad++ without any macros or anything else:

1. Click Edit -> Blank Operations -> EOL to space
   [All the items should now be in a single line separated by a 'space']
2. Select any 'space' and do a Replace All (by ',')

Comment: Simple and elegant, nice

Comment: @trishul Really Nice.

Comment: Very simple solution

Answer (score 37):

[fapDaddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15741232/111424) using a macro pointed me in the right direction.

Here's precisely what worked for me.

1. Place the cursor after the first data item. [image]
2. Click 'Macro > Start Recording' in the menu. [image]
3. Type this sequence: <kbd>Comma</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>. [image]
4. Click 'Macro > Stop recording' in the menu. [image]
5. Click 'Macro > Run a Macro Multiple Times...' in the menu. [image]
6. Click 'Run until the end of file' and click 'Run'. [image]
7. Remove any trailing characters. [image]
8. Done!

[image]

Comment: This method is slow for thousands of data items.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Such a great info, will be useful in many similar situations. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. It's interesting.

Answer (score 16):

For Notepad++ 5.9

1. Press **Ctrl+H**
2. Select Search mode **Extended(\n, \r, \t, \o, \x...)**
3. Enter Find what: **\r\n**
4. Enter Replace with: **,**
5. **Replace_All** should get the required result.

Comment: This answer repeats the accepted answer and this answer refers to an antique version of Notepad++, version 7.4.x is now available. Welcome to Stack Overflow but please make you answers supply new information or give new insights. Repeating existing answers is not useful.

Comment: For newer versions of npp this is the better way to to this.

Comment: This is the easiest answer.  I should not have to go into Regular Expression mode just to replace newlines with commas.  N++ actually works correctly whereas other editors interpret "\n" as a carriage return AND line feed, which confused me at first.

Answer (score 14):

A regex match with `\s+` worked for me:

[image]

Comment: BTW: it seems to me that a regex match with `$^` should work, but it, instead, matches `^$`.

Comment: Using the "Extended" option right above the "Regular expression" option (in your screen shot) is actually the easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

Place your cursor after **Apples**, under **Macro** Tab, select **Start Recording**.
Type the comma(**,**) character, space( ) character, and press **End** key, under Macro tab, select **Stop Recording**.

Ctrl+Shift+P for single playback.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.
What if I have 5000++ words? Do I need to run the macro for all of them individually?

Is there an easier method?

Comment: If you'll have to perform similar task in the future, you might want to write a script for it. Easy way out is probably just go to the Macro Tab and select run the macro multiple times. It will be done in seconds.

Comment: +1 Your answer pointed me in the right direction. In [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17811850/111424) I documented exactly what worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

### USE Chrome's Search Bar

1-press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>
2-paste the copied text in **search bar**
3-press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the text again from search
4-paste in **Notepad++**
5-replace `'space'` with `','`

[image: 1-click for image]
[image: 2-click for image]

Answer (score 3):

This might sound strange but you can remove next line by copying the whole text and pasting it in firefox search bar, and then re-pasting it in notepad++

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

Comment: Please improve this answer. Links to images won't be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line `cc.rnl ', '` of ConyEdit (a plugin) to replace new lines with the contents you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have recorded a macro and shared it below. You have to edit %AppData%\Notepad++\Shortcuts.xml and paste the macro and restart Notepad++.exe

Start macro recording then Go to find and replace, choose extended, find "\r\n" and replace with "," comma. Recorded this and then saved the macro from menu.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<NotepadPlus>
  <Macros>
    <Macro name="Replace Newlines with Comma" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="188">
      <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
      <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\r\n" />
      <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
      <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="," />
      <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
      <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    </Macro>
  </Macros>
</NotepadPlus>
```