# Find and replace with a newline in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, newline

I am trying out the new Microsoft Visual Studio Code editor in Linux Fedora environment. I would like to know how to replace new line (\n) in place of some other text.

For example, I have html text like this

```
<tag><tag>
```

which I would like to replace as

```
<tag>
<tag>
```

In sublime I would use regex pattern and find *"><"* and replace with *">\n<"* How do I accomplish this in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Did you see this.? **https://stackoverflow.com/a/50042582/6597375**

Comment: Actually not a duplicate: The other question asks about carriage return, this one about newline, and no the answer does not work for carriage return for some reason.

Comment: Shift + Enter will do the job

Answer (score 1392, accepted):

In the local searchbox (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>) you can insert newlines by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image: Image of multiline search in local search]

If you use the global search (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>) you can insert newlines by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image: Image of multiline search in global search]

If you want to search for multilines by the character literal, remember to check the **rightmost regex icon**.

[image: Image of regex mode in search replace]

---

In previous versions of Visual Studio code this was difficult or impossible. Older versions require you to use the regex mode, older versions yet did not support newline search whatsoever.

Comment: Nor in version 0.10.3. But there is an extension that can do this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/jmallien.ReplaceWithNewline

Comment: Note that while *replacing* with newline characters is supported, *finding* newline characters still does not work until https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/313 is fixed.

Comment: This doesn't work on the mac - it literally replaces \r or \n

Comment: Note that regex mode must be on. If not, it won't use a newline.

Comment: Down voted because the answer from Eric Bole-Feysot provides a quick solution for the latest versions of VS code.

Comment: @NigelDavies It's not a competition.

Comment: It's important to emphasize that regex mode must be enabled

Comment: regex search for `\\n` and replace with `\n` works for me, using 1.25.0

Comment: If you use CRLF, it also only `\n`, not `\r\n` like in Notepad++, for example.

Comment: With regex mode enabled, `\r` is interpreted as a carriage return only in the Find box, but not Replace for some reason. But I can't say that in https://stackoverflow.com/q/32464102/5447019 because it's locked.

Comment: regex search for [\r\n]+ works great for me. Credit to:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15743435/2614736

Answer (score 261):

With VS Code [release 1.38](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_workbench) you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the editor find box to add a newline character.

[image]

With VS Code [release 1.30](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_workbench) you can type `Shift` + `Enter` in the search box to add a newline character without needing to use regex mode.

[image]

Since VS Code [release 1.3](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/June_2016#_multiline-find), the regex find has supported newline characters. To use this feature set the find window to regex mode and use `\n` as the newline character.

[image: Multiline find in VS Code gif]

Comment: This gave me a little push into the right direction. 
I needed the empty line to replace HTML comments: ```<!--[\s\S\n]*?-->```
And I was missing the \n :)

Comment: I am loving this feature, works in the search and replace fields too!

Comment: Still doesn't work in the ctrl+shift+f search sidebar... -_-

Answer (score 85):

In version 1.1.1:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Check the regular exp icon `.*`
- Search: `><`
- Replace: `>\n<`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that you have to press the regexp icon!

Answer (score 50):

Also note, after hitting the regex icon,  to actually replace `\n` text with a newline, I had to use `\\n` as search and `\n` as replace.

Comment: Hi @Stiv great tip but this really should have been a comment since it does not answer the question.

Comment: Might not have looked in the comments... this was the answer I needed. Thanks @stiv!

Answer (score 32):

- Control F for search, or Control Shift F for global search
- Replace `><` by `>\n<` with Regular Expressions enabled

[image]

Answer (score 19):

A possible workaround would be to use the multi-cursor.
select the >< part of your example
use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or select all occurrences.
Then use the arrow keys to move all the cursors between the tags and press enter to insert a newline everywhere.

This won't work in all situations.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for select next match, which adds the next match to the selection and adds a cursor.
And use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to skip a selection.

Comment: `Ctrl+D` is great! You may need to press `Ctrl+F` first and after a few `Ctrl+D`s or skipping with `Ctrl+K Ctrl+D`, you may press `Esc` to place the cursor in all selections!

Answer (score 12):

At least for me in VS Code Version 1.62.3 on Windows and VS Code Version 1.75 on MacOS (Ventura) it is working with regex, as shown below:

1. Replace Menu

   Windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

   Mac: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. Activate "Use Regular Expression (ALT + R)"

   Windows: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

   Mac: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
3. Use `<>` in the Search field and `>\n<` in the Replace field
4. Press "Replace All (CRTL+ALT+Enter)" with an empty field

   Windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

   Mac: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

In case of the initial question, it would look like this:

[image]

---

**Hint:**
Use `[\n]` or `\n` to find all newlines

[image]

In addition, to find newlines at the **beginning** of a line, you can also use `^[\n]` or `^\n`:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

On my mac version of VS Code, I select the section, then the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to remove line breaks.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, then select regex (*) and write \n

Shorter version: 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> \n

Answer (score 1):

with v1.31.1 in RegEx mode the Replace All functionality is broken.  clicking that button replaces only one instance

Answer (score -2):

In case if you want to remove extra new lines from code then use this in vs code find a section

```
for opening the find box use ctrl + f in vs code
```

then find all new lines from code type this in the find box

```
^\n
```

also only choosing Use regular expression option means the last option of the find box. After selecting this you will see all new lines on the code highlighted.
then on replace box leave it as it is and click replace all option.

Same as if you want to add a new line where ever you found space then
on find, box provide one space than on replace box add

```
^\n and click return all
```