# Use a carriage return in VS Code replace string

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am refactoring some code in the [Visual Studio Code editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/) but cannot figure out how to have find and replace insert a carriage return. I have tried copying/pasting a carriage return. I have also tried turning on regular expressions and entering `\n`.