# Replace line breaks

Tags: replace, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code for several things. Everything is working fine, but I cannot get one specific thing to work.

I need the ability to remove line breaks from the text.

Example:

```
first line
second line
```

Should become:

```
first linesecondline
```

Since a recent update it is possible to search for line breaks with using ^$.
It is described here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/314

The problem I have is that when I use this for replacing, it does actually "add" to the line break and does not "replace" it.

Comment: It might be nice if you showed what you mean with code examples, not just of what you want to happen, but what you've tried, and the results of that attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a carriage return in VS Code replace string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464102/use-a-carriage-return-in-vs-code-replace-string)

Answer (score 91):

The latest version of VS Code has a shortcut to **join lines** (some may say *remove breaks*) from selection: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: was `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `J` for me. Depends on your default key mappings.

Comment: Do you have the command name ? Both shortcuts are invalid on my MacOS setup

Comment: I am on Version: 1.46.1 on a Mac.  Still works for me.  Select the text with the line-breaks, then CTRL+J and they are removed.

Comment: Feel like this is really not a great answer as CTRL + J is just a shortcut to a command and it won't necessarily work on all systems/in the future etc. It didn't work for me on my Linux/KDE setup, but thankfully Apostolis' answer gave the actual command name "Join Lines".

Comment: @maxime the command is called "Join lines".

Comment: It is called "Join Lines" , not in your answer "remove breaks from selection"

Comment: Shortcut didn't work for me on v1.74.3, but the `join lines` command is just what I needed.

Comment: You save me a atleast an hour. :)

Answer (score 75):

I found that (at least on Windows) the solution was to use search and replace with a regular expression. Search for `$\n` and replace with nothing to get rid of the newlines. Note that the newline character that we want to replace is placed after the end of line matcher (`$`).

Comment: I found this answer especially helpful. Not that the other answers like the "Join Lines" shortcut doesn't work... but this answer gave me even more flexibility for situations where I want to replace the line endings with something else.

Comment: Confirming that it works also under macOS

Comment: This used to work for me but doesn't any more (MacOS). The regex does not recognize any line breaks.

Answer (score 71):

@tripleonard hint did not work for me (no shortcut key assigned), so what I did was  first <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to list all commands and then just type `Join lines`

Comment: Also, `F1` is a shorter way to perform `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`

Answer (score 22):

In my case shorcut in VS Code was not set. It took me a while to find out what command in VS Code am I looking for. For other with same problem it is: "Join lines".

Answer (score 20):

I'm able to manage this with the search and replace tool and "Use Regular Expression" enabled. Search for the pattern `\n$` and replace with `$`

Comment: This one didn't work for me, but Henrik Hansson's very similar $\n did work.  Weird.

Answer (score 11):

Turn on [regex mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-find-and-replace-options) and find and replace.

Search for `\n` and replace with nothing.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\n` to search for new lines

but while finding/searching,

the `Use Regular Expression` option should be enabled

[image: Find and Replace - VS Code - Use Regular Expression]

Answer (score 8):

Select the new line, and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (and hold it).
Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, you will be able to replace it with whatever you need.

Answer (score 5):

On Mac, use `cmd+a` to select all lines. Then, use `cmd+shift+p` to open commands and type Join Line and click on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Press ctrl+f or ctrl + h
Copy and past this ^(\s)*$\n expression into top input field
after click on the * icon, then you can see all white lines break.

Past bottom input field = \n //one line break
That means what you want to replate in white line break
After click on the Replace or Replace All Icon button

https://bitcoden.com/answers/visual-studio-code-delete-all-blank-lines-regex
```