# Global find and replace with newline in Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Suppose I want to *remove* all lines matching a regex in my project. Is there a way to do that?

Using the global find and replace function with regexes enabled I've tried:

1. Replace `foo|bar` with an empty string. This doesn't work because it leaves the line there with an empty string. I want the newline removed.
2. Replace `(foo|bar)\n` with an empty string. This doesn't actually match anything.
3. Replace `(foo|bar)$` with an empty string. Again, doesn't match anything.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: It seems like some of my files have Windows line endings so `(foo|bar)\r?\n` *does* match. However when you replace it with an empty string it actually still leaves the line endings there.

Here's a test case:

```
a
foo
b
```

It should end up like this:

```
a
b
```

Not like this:

```
a

b
```

Comment: "when you replace it with an empty string it actually still leaves the line endings there" - that works as expected for me: http://i.imgur.com/7C4QES2.gifv

Comment: What if you do a find and replace on `^(?:foo|bar)\s*` ?

Comment: Related with no answer: [Replace line breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312194/replace-line-breaks)

Comment: @Gama11: That's in the single-file find-and-replace. I mean the *global* one (the magnifying glass on the left hand side). Not sure of its official name.

Answer (score 0):

`foo\n^` and `(foo|bar)\n^` both work.

I just tested in my vs code  - and you leave the replacement string blank

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible to remove entire lines with the search-across-files feature.

I'm guessing the original problem was due to a bug or otherwise unwanted behavior in an older version of VSCode.  With VSCode 1.37.1, so long as the `\n` is included in the regex, the line is removed.  In particular, the regex `(foo|bar)\n`, described in the original question as not working, now works fine.

Before:

[image: Screenshot before replacement]

After pressing the "Replace All" button:

[image: Screenshot after replacement]

Related observations:

- This same regex works even if I set the file line endings to CRLF.
- Appending `^` makes no difference.  That's a bit surprising, but perhaps "after newline" counts as "beginning of line".
- Appending `$` causes the regex to not match anything.  That is quite surprising given the behavior of `^`.
- I looked through the search configuration settings, but nothing seemed like it could affect this.