# Visual studio code - cannot search for new lines using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

As the title says, in VSC, I cannot search for new lines using the Regular Expression mode:

[image]

Why is this? From what I searched online, this should be possible

Comment: you can try  `\r\n`

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35312194/3832970), does it help?

Comment: @LuisFernando same error

Comment: @LuisFernando: If `\n` is not allowed, that won't work either.

Comment: @SLaks its bug?

Comment: Maybe version specific. I can't reproduce on v1.20

Comment: Try \\n or update to v1.23 that comment seems to have gone away.  I used to get it "literal \n notallowed"in earlier versions.

Comment: @Mark I updated and I get the same error. If i use \\n, then there won't be any findings, but in fact there should be

Comment: try this: `[\r\n]`

Comment: I can reproduce this (bug?) in v1.25.1 and [\r\n] does seem to work for some reason without error but it matches the whole line not just the end char.