# How to remove Multiple Whitespace/Endline from Multiple Files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, refactoring, code-formatting, removing-whitespace

I can able to do the find and replace for a single file by putting `^\s*$\n` and replacing it with nothing. But Visual Studio Code is not allowing the same for multiple files.

> Literal '\n' is not allowed
>   [image]

How can I do this in Visual Studio Code or Any other faster solution? BTW I am doing it on node.js project.

**Edit**
VS Code not allowing `\n` for multi file find and replace
[image]

Comment: In the "**files to include/exclude**" field put in `*.*` or the files you want to include.

Comment: No, by default it include all files.

Comment: I am able to perform non '\n' replace on multiple files.

Comment: Try using `\\n` instead of `\n`... see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43483515/499581

Comment: ^\s*$\\n not working. It is considering it as slash + n string

Comment: It might be having an issue with the `$` delimiter in your pattern, but who knows, maybe it's a bug? Have you tried as a test `^\s*\n` or `^\s*\n$`?

Comment: No, Visual Studio Code is just not allowing '\n' for find and replace for multiple files. I am adding the screenshot above Question as well.

Comment: I would report that as a bug, because it really shouldn’t do that imo. Good luck!

Comment: Also, try `\x0A` or `\u000A` and if those do not work, it is really some hardcoded limitation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with `[\n\r]` instead of `\n`

```
^\s*$[\n\r]
```

[image: find with regex in vscode]

Btw, it seems `^\s*$` finds greatly more `empty lines` than above.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) this worked. I hope VS Code will add such option before we have to come up with complicated solution ;)

Comment: Sorry,It looks like your syntax was able to find all those lines but when I am replacing it, it doesn't work. Did you tried removing the empty lines with same syntax in multiple files?

Comment: It looks like a bug in VS Code. Can you please check on your side. Will be great help :-) for future projects as well.

Comment: Sorry to say that `find & replace in files` in `vscode` seems not working properly in some regex pattern at this time and works some differently from `find` for `a file`. I recommend using other text editors(e.g. `notepad++`, etc) for finding & replacing in multiple files with `regex`